# Passing List of Class Objects to another class

Tags: c#

i am trying to pass a List of class objects to another class, in this case I'm initilising a form class and need to send two values:

Class Object:

```
public class catData
{
  public string catName;
  public string modGUID;
  public string versionLocal;
  public string versionServer;
  public bool onServer;
}
```

In Class1 i have the list and need to send to Class2 upon initilisation.

Class1:

```
String catExportTXT = "txt";
List<catData> mainCatSet = new List<catData>();

using (var catForm = new Class2(catExportTXT, mainCatSet))
{
  var result = catForm.ShowDialog();
  if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
  {
    localvar = catForm.selectedCats;
  }
  else
  {
    Environment.Exit(0);
  }
}
```

The problem here is Class2 has no definition for the class Object (catData) so i cannot send it directly as a parameter.

Can anyone advise on how i might go about defining the class object in Class2 so i can send the values?

Many Thanks

Comment: Why are you referring to your catData class as class Object ? What's Class2 ?

Comment: I'm using that class as a data type. Object of type catData are what's in the list that needs to be sent to Class2 (a form class, see ShowDialog).

Comment: So you want to access the data-class `catData` in `Class2` without referencing `catData` from the latter? This is simply not possible and makes no sense at all. However you may simply split the properties of your data-class and pass every one as single value to `Class2`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't expalin very well, we have List<classObject> on Class1, this needs to be sent to Class2. Class2 is a form class. I need to figure the best way to pass the List to Class2.
Edit: Saw your edit, it seems there is a way to reference the class object definition from Class1 in Class2 but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Why can't you reference catData from Class2 by adding a using <namespace> directive at the top of Class2 ?

Comment: They're both in the same namespace, i can of course 'reference' catData but i haven't figured out a way to do that so that I'm able to reference it in Class2 as a type (example): List<catData> mainCatSet = new List<catData>(); Any ideas on how to reference catData so it's possible to use it as a type in Class 2?

Comment: Can you post your constructor for Class 2 (or whatever bit that's making use of catData).

Comment: Sure, public catalogueSelect(String catLoc, List<Object> cats) is something i've tried but that won't work as the catData class isn't generic. I just can't see a clear cut way to pass this list between the classes without wildly breaking the one-class, one-task rule.

Comment: Why don't you change public catalogueSelect(String catLoc, List<Object> cats) to be public catalogueSelect(String catLoc, List<catData> cats) ? What do you mean by 'one-class, one task' rule ?

Comment: Is it possible that you simply declared the class `catData` inside the class `Class1`? This would make it an inner class, which in turn would require you to use `Class1.catData` inside `Class2` when referring to that class

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in Class2?  I can see it is a dialog but what type of information are you really trying to pass?  Are there other objects to pass in?  How are you intending to use the data that you pass to Class2?

Comment: Is it simply a generic selection dialog you are trying to create?

Comment: Yes that's it, pass these values to the dialog, display them line by line, select those required and pass back the user selection to the calling class. I just found it benificial and more readable to group each set of information into a class object and the add those to a collection. Is there anything you would suggest? Is this a bad approach?

Comment: no, passing lists of Objects around is not a good idea because it's not type safe. Change Object list to catData list because that's what you're expecting.

Comment: That was just an example which didn't actually work, what i've now done is implimented an interface for the catData class so both Class1 and Class2 can access catData.

Comment: If the code posted isn't representative of your problem, then please update your question.

Comment: I think giving consideration to auburg's comment about type-safe using an interface is going to be the most useful.  There are many ways to do this but I will have to switch to my windows computer to check syntax before submitting anything.  I suspect there will be a number of suggested answers in-between!  But for the sake of sharing...

Answer (score 1):

OK how about this:

1) Create an interface to provide a displayable name.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides an interface for human-readable names in objects.
/// </summary>
public interface IDisplayName
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a name to display in the application to end-users.
    /// </summary>
    string DisplayName { get; }
}
```

2)  Create an interface for selectable objects.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides an interface used to allow selection of an object in the user interface.
/// </summary>
public interface ISelectable : IDisplayName
{
}
```

3) Assign the interface and create the property on the catData object.

```
public class catData : ISelectable
{
    public string catName;
    public string modGUID;
    public string versionLocal;
    public string versionServer;
    public bool onServer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a name to display in the application to end-users.
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayName {  get { return catName; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

4) The Class2 form (with an example but missing core selection actions obviously).  If you are using a generic list control consider overriding ToString() in catData as above.

```
public partial class Class2<T> : Form where T : ISelectable
{
    private IEnumerable<ISelectable> selectableItems;

    public Class2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Class2(string exportText, IEnumerable<T> list) : this()
    {
        this.selectableItems = list;
    }

    public T { get; set; }
    public List<T> SelectedItems { get; set; }

    private void Class2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ISelectable item in selectableItems)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(item.DisplayName);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

5) Utilize in your main app like this:

```
String catExportTXT = "txt";
List<catData> mainCatSet = new List<catData>();

using (var selectForm = new Class2<catData>(catExportTXT, mainCatSet))
{
    var result = selectForm.ShowDialog();
    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var localvar = selectForm.SelectedItem;
    }
    else
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Note in example above Class2 does NOT need to know about catData class as Class2 allows anything with an ISelectable interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to do that but one option is using an array of dynamics.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new Class1();
        c1.SendCats();
    }
}
class Class1
{
    public void SendCats()
    {
        var catData = new[]
        {
            new { name = "cat1", version = 1 },
            new { name = "cat2", version = 2 }
        };
        var c2 = new Class2(catData);
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public Class2(dynamic[] catData)
    {
        foreach (var cat in catData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", cat.name, cat.version);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
cat1 1
cat2 2
```

Also, if needed you can convert a list of Cat object into a dynamic array

```
var catList = new List<Cat>();
catList.Add(new Cat { Name = "cat1", Version = 1 });
catList.Add(new Cat { Name = "cat2", Version = 2 });
var catData = catList.Select(c => new { name = c.Name, version = c.Version }).ToArray();
var c2 = new Class2(catData);
```