# Passing List<Object> between classes

Tags: c#

I have `Class1`, this class needs to send a List of class objects `List<classObject>` to `Class2`, if this were `List<String>` it would be easy enough as i would, for example, send it directly as a parameter.

As i have an object that's defined in `Class1` as `classObject` it seems i'm unable to reference it in the constructor at `Class2`.

What i want to ensure is that proper OO practices are adhered to so don't want to implement any direct dependence between the classes. Is there a way to send the `List<classObject>` from `Class1` to `Class2`, generic objects possibly?

EDIT:

here's an example of what i've tried, this doesn't work but hopefully gives you a good idea of what i'm trying the acheive:

Class1:

```
public class catData
{
    public string catName;
    public string modGUID;
    public string versionLocal;
    public string versionServer;
    public bool onServer;
}

void allCats()
{
    List<catData> mainCatSet = new List<catData>();

    mainCatSet.Add(new catData { name = "abc", tel = "none"});

    var catForm = new catalogueSelect(mainCatSet)
}
```

Class 2:

```
public catalogueSelect(List<Object> cats)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //do soemthing with List 'cats'
}
```

That's one appraoch i've tried but it doesn't look like that's going to work, is there a way to acheive sending the List from Class1 to Class 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably by using an interface or shared class library, but this can't be answered without you showing some relevant code.

Comment: You already asked that question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398511/passing-list-of-class-objects-to-another-class

Comment: if you really need to use class from other assembly - then you have to add reference to it, or use interface as CodeCaster allready told (aslo have to reference assembly with that interface )

Comment: Thanks guys, i've added an edit with some additional info but from what you say it seems an assembly or interface sit he best way forward.

Comment: If you know the list coming into `catalogueSelect` is going to be of type `List<catData>` then there doesn't seem to be a need for generics.

Comment: Even if you cast to `object` and sent it, you would need to cast back for it to be usable so you would still have dependence.

Comment: I'm going to impliment an Interface so catData is avaliable for all classes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you're having trouble reference your `catData` class since it's in a different location from you `catelogueSelect` method.

One solution to this is to create an `ICatData` interface in a common location and use that as the `List` type as the parameter.

This allows you to separate the definition and implementation of your class and better adhere to OOP principles.

For example:

In some common location:

```
public interface ICatData
{
    string catName;
    string modGUID;
    string versionLocal;
    string versionServer;
    bool onServer;
}
```

Class1:

```
public class catData : ICatData
{
    public string catName;
    public string modGUID;
    public string versionLocal;
    public string versionServer;
    public bool onServer;
}

void allCats()
{
    List<ICatData> mainCatSet = new List<ICatData>();    
    mainCatSet.Add(new catData { name = "abc", tel = "none"});    
    var catForm = new catalogueSelect(mainCatSet)
}
```

Class 2:

```
public catalogueSelect(List<ICatData> cats)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //do soemthing with List 'cats'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, that clears it up nicely :)

Comment: Quick question...do i also have to define catData as inheriting from IcatData in Class 2?

Comment: With this method `Class 2` doesn't need to know about `catData`, just the interface.

Comment: thanks for your help :)